# Rails 4: routing custom create actions to two different new actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my controller, I've created two seperate `new` actions. One is `asknew`, the other is `offernew`. I need to set a value of each when they are created, so I've tried to create a separate `create` action for each, in which I can set the two different values.

```
  def newoffer
     @request = Request.new
     @request.requesttype = "offer"
  end

  def newask
     @request = Request.new
     @request.requesttype = "ask"
  end
```

Custom create actions:

```
def createask
   @request = Request.new(request_params)
   @request.requesttype = "ask"

respond_to do |format|
    if @request.save
            format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def createoffer
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    @request.requesttype = "offer"

respond_to do |format|
  if @request.save
    format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

All the actions are working fine, but I don't know how to have the `new` actions route to their respective `create` actions. BTW, what are some good resources on routing? It's what I've been having the most trouble with.

Comment: Don't see why do you really need to duplicate all that code for making only 1 difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid separate new and create actions to set the requesttype default value you can pass the value in through the url and store it in a hidden form field:

**Links:**

```
link_to('New offer', new_request_path(requesttype: 'offer'))
link_to('New ask', new_request_path(requesttype: 'ask'))
```

**Controller:**

```
def new
  @request = Request.new(requesttype: params[:requesttype])
end
```

**Form**

```
form_for(@request) do |f|
  f.hidden_field :requesttype
end
```

Make sure you validate requesttype in the model layer in case someone messes with the URL

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :requesttype, in: %w{ offer ask }
end
```

Comment: Thought there must be a better way. Thanks!

Comment: How could I do a conditional dependent on the value of requesttype in my new view, so I can have a header like "New Offer" or "New Request"?